# how to display ranges in filters

Tags: filter, range, ease-of-use

I have some filters, and I want to display ranges, I am just not sure what the most intuitive way to achieve this is.

So for the first filter, it would from 0 to 10, there are several ways to display it:

- -10
- 0-10
- less than 10
- < 10

Then the ones containing ranges

- 10 to 20
- 10 - 20

And then the last ones

- 100 +
- more than 100
- 100 <

What method is most intuitive?

Comment: Note that not all of your alternatives are indeed equivalent. For example, "less than 10" and "< 10" refer to numbers up to 9, excluding 10, while "0-10" may be interpreted as an interval including both 0 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

A little competitive audit might shed some light on your question. I'll get you started.

Here's Amazon, Best Buy, and Target, left to right.

[image: Amazon]
[image: Best Buy]
[image: Target]

Best Buy is a little pedantic, with their "$25 - $49.99" and the other two are imprecise. Where do $25 items fall in Amazon? Where does Target list the $14.99 products?

They must have both decided that a little imprecision doesn't matter. It looks like Amazon lists $25 items in both filters where they fit, and Target lists $14.99 items in the "$0 - $14" range. And that's fine.

You ask what's most intuitive, but it looks like "intuitive enough" is good enough for these giant stores.

(Note that they all show the number of items within each filter, which helps users understand what they'll be getting before they click.)

Answer (score 0):

Greater than and less than signs have been abused and used for all sorts of things in the digital age. No longer the resolute resource they once were.

Spaces are more important than anything else.

Space around your choices, the space between your choices and the space between range values and their indicator. Get the spacing right, and I'd suggest dashes, plus and minus are the best indicator.

Get spacing wrong, or not have the liberty of other forms of visual distinction, and not need to be international, and using the words is going to be better.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest, unambiguous way is surely:

**from 0 to 10 (included)**

It is preferable to specify 'included' as it is generally a missing (and important) information in filters.

If place is really a concern, as this might be the case for your question, another option could be:

**up to 10**